# Celery Tasks not Running on Mac M2 (Process 'ForkPoolWorker' exited with 'signal 11 (SIGSEGV)')

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, apple-m1, task-queue

I am encountering an issue while trying to run Celery tasks on my Mac M1 machine. The error message I'm getting is as follows:

```
The process has forked and you cannot use this CoreFoundation functionality safely. You MUST exec().
Break on __THE_PROCESS_HAS_FORKED_AND_YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY___YOU_MUST_EXEC__() to debug.
[2023-11-20 15:51:19,174: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-8' pid:5547 exited with 'signal 11 (SIGSEGV)'
```

I am using Celery for my Django app task processing, and this issue seems to be related to forking on the M2 architecture.

I initially attempted to resolve the issue by exporting `OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES`, which seemed to work for a brief period. However, the problem has resurfaced, and this solution no longer has any effect.

It's worth noting that I am currently running `MacOS Sonama 14.2 Beta` on my machine.

> Interestingly, I encountered and successfully resolved this problem once before while on the same beta program.

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.